# "No module named 'core'" after rename of modules

Tags: python, setuptools

I have the following directory structure:

```
src/
  |- setup.py
  |- prettylogger
    |- __init__.py
    |- core.py
  |- transgression
    |- __init__.py
    |- core.py
```

The problem I'm having is that it doesn't quite setup correctly. What I *want* it to do is to install two packages - *prettylogger* and *transgression* so that *prettylogger* can be imported independently of *transgression*, and vice versa, using `from prettylogger.core import PrettyLogger` (class `PrettyLogger` is contained within `prettylogger/core.py`.

I've tried the setup.py file following this post, but with little success. It seems to install a .egg file into `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` (I'm on a mac) for prettylogger and transgression, but when I run: `transgression` at the command line, I get:

```
  File "/usr/local/bin/transgression", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('transgression==0.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'transgression')()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 318, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2221, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/transgression/core.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/configurator/core.py", line 16, in <module>
ImportError: No module named core
```

I have a test suite in transgression/transgression-test.py, and when I cd to that directory and run it, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/transgression/core.py", line 16, in <module>
    from prettylogger.core import PrettyLogger
ImportError: No module named core
```

So, it seems to be that it can't find this module. I just renamed the module from prettylogger.py to core.py, because I wanted to be able to use: `from prettylogger.core import PrettyLogger` instead of `from prettylogger.prettylogger import PrettyLogger`.

**Setup.py**:

```
from setuptools import setup                                                    
import os                                                                       

setup(name='prettylogger',                                                      
      version='0.0.1',                                                          
      description='A logging utility package designed for command line use',    
      py_modules=['prettylogger.core'],
      # Note: I also have tried packages=['prettylogger'], here                                        
      install_requires=['ansicolors'] 
)                                                                               

setup(name='transgression',                                                     
      version='0.0.1',                                                          
      description='Generic binary regression finding utility',
      packages=['transgression'],                                               
      entry_points={ 'console_scripts': [                                       
        'transgression = transgression.core:main'] },                           
      install_requires=['prettylogger']                         
)
```

Comment: add an empty file `__init__.py` to folders `prettylogger` and `transgression`

Comment: Do the modules import from the shell without any problems? `transgression` might be failing because it can't find `configurator`, but I don't see any problem with the `prettylogger` setup.

Comment: Well, actually, I have three modules: configurator, which depends on prettylogger, and transgression, which depends on configurator and prettylogger. I removed one of them because it seemed unnecessary (as I can copy the config for one to the other once I figure out what I'm doing wrong). If I'm in the src/ directory, then I can import both packages fine from `python` (i.e. the interpreter), but they don't seem to be installed to the global site-packages, as I can't import them from any other directory.

Comment: Have you checked sys.path yet? It may not be installing them in the right place.

Comment: From the interpreter, my sys.path shows: ```['', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/prettylogger-0.0.1-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/configurator-0.0.1-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/transgression-0.0.1-py2.7.egg',  ... other stuff ... ]``` So I know they are there... it's just that `from prettylogger.core import PrettyLogger` doesn't allow me to import the class.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have an `__init__.py` file in your package directories? Python requires this file in order to recogize the directory and its contents to be packages (although I think this may have changed in the newer Python 3.x versions).

The `__init__.py` file can be empty, it doesn't need any additional content.

Comment: I don't have an init in the SRC directory (top level) but I do have one I every other directory, although they are empty files.

Answer (score 0):

Files named `__init__.py` are used to mark directories on disk as a Python package directories.

If you remove the `__init__.py` file, Python will no longer look for submodules inside that directory, so attempts to import the module will fail.

If you have lots of folders, then create the empty `__init__.py` file in each folder. for eg:

```
src/
  |- __init__.py
  |- setup.py
  |- prettylogger
    |- __init__.py
    |- core.py
  |- transgression
    |- __init__.py
    |- core.py
```

Comment: I don't have an init in the SRC directory (top level) but I do have one I every other directory, although they are empty files.